# Как изменить системно размер изображения в Android studio?

Tags: java, android, изображения, android-studio

Есть несколько изображений одного размера. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на изображения его размер увеличился. Соответсвенно при дальнейшем нажатии на другое изображение размер первого возвращался в норму, а размер этого "другого" стал больше.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: что значит "изображения"? png, jpg, bmp файлы? ImageView? Что? покажите в конце концов ваш код. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Имеел ввиду ImageView. Думал и без кода будет понятно

Comment: Я использовал этот вариант...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301894/how-to-zoom-in-out-imageview-on-click-using-java-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ здесь

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U51k118-bFg

сделал примерно так

```
        monday=(ImageView)findViewById(MONDAY);
        tuesday=(ImageView)findViewById(TUESDAY);
        wednesday=(ImageView)findViewById(WEDNESDAY);
        thurday=(ImageView)findViewById(THURDAY);
        friday=(ImageView)findViewById(FRIDAY);
        saturday=(ImageView)findViewById(SATURDAY);
        sunday=(ImageView)findViewById(SUNDAY);

        layoutMonday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)monday.getLayoutParams();
        layoutTuesday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tuesday.getLayoutParams();
        layoutWednesday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)wednesday.getLayoutParams();
        layoutThurday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)thurday.getLayoutParams();
        layoutFriday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)friday.getLayoutParams();
        layoutSaturday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)saturday.getLayoutParams();
        layoutSunday = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)sunday.getLayoutParams();

        bigWidth=layoutThurday.width;
        bigHeight=layoutThurday.height;
        smallHeight=layoutMonday.height;
        smallWidth=layoutMonday.width;
```

Изменение размера при нажатии клавиши:

```
....
layoutMonday.width=smallWidth;
layoutMonday.height=smallHeight;
....
layoutThurday.width=bigWidth;
layoutThurday.height=bigHeight;
```

Comment: Буду блогадарен, если кто-то предложит более рациональный вариант, если такой есть